# Trigger a Vue components method by property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is it possible to trigger a Vue components method by handling the methods name to one of it's properties?

```
// main.vue
<navigation :button-left="goback()"></navigation>



// navigation.component.vue
...
props: ["buttonLeft"],
...
methods: {
  goback() {
    console.log('Run this.');
  },
},
...
```

I tried it like this but it gives me an error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "goback" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Comment: what's your use case?

Comment: The intention is to handle routing with the navigation. The buttons of the navigation differ from page to page. For some buttons it's necessary to handle a fixed routing path but for others it's just intended to go one step back in the routing history which should be done by a simple method.

Comment: What is meant to trigger the method execution?

Comment: did you try to emit events from child component to the parent component and do what you want in the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible.

The easiest way would be to pass a plain string, eg

```
<navigation button-left="goback" />
```

Note there's no `v-bind`.

Then in your component, you can use the prop value. Something like...

```
export default {
  template: `<button @click="runButtonLeft">Go</button>`,
  props: ['buttonLeft'],
  methods: {
    runButtonLeft () {
      if (typeof this[this.buttonLeft] === 'function') {
        this[this.buttonLeft]()
      } else {
        console.error('Invalid method name:', this.buttonLeft)
      }
    },
    goback () {
      console.log('Run this.')
    }
  }
}
```

You didn't specify what should be used to trigger the method execution so I've gone with a *click* event.

Comment: Yes this would work, but I'm struggling to think of a use case for this.  If you want different functionality of an event (button left in this case) every time you implement the component, I would probably emit that he event happened, and let the parent component decide what needs to happen. Like `<navigation @button-left="call-some-method-on-parent-component" />`

Comment: I adopted this way and it fits my need. This is right for me. Thanks a lot.